# How to enable different page headers on last and middle pages in jasper reports?

Tags: jasper-reports

I need to enable the reports with 3 types of the page headers: "first page header", "middle pages header" and "last page header". All of these headers can have different number of report elements and on different positions. Same goes for the footers.

[image]

**NOTE:** The report must support the report elements like **jr:table** or **jr:list** in its `Detail` band. These element must be supplied with the data via xml datasources.

I was able to simulate first page header by using `Title` band, but I'm having problems enabling "middle pages header" and "last page header". This is what I'm trying to do:

```
<pageHeader>
<band height="100" splitType="Stretch">
    <frame>
        <reportElement x="0" y="0" height="100" width="555" uuid="f788c74b-6853-4bc7-8ed7-5e3d538287c9" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true">
            <printWhenExpression>
                <![CDATA[new Boolean($V{PAGE_NUMBER} == $V{PAGE_COUNT})]]>
            </printWhenExpression>
        </reportElement>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="1" y="1" width="100" height="20" uuid="9777208b-5323-4045-aa49-a849d5c00c89"/>
            <text><![CDATA[LAST PAGE HEADER TEXT 1]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="50" y="10" width="200" height="50" uuid="15313676-09e6-4d17-ac75-2df99f61bfee"/>
            <text><![CDATA[LAST PAGE HEADER TEXT 2]]></text>
        </staticText>
    </frame>
    <frame>
        <reportElement x="0" y="0" height="100" width="555" uuid="65577abd-8717-477a-f27e-c70e9eba46af" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true">
            <printWhenExpression>
                <![CDATA[new Boolean($V{PAGE_NUMBER} != 1) && new Boolean($V{PAGE_NUMBER} != $V{PAGE_COUNT})]]>
            </printWhenExpression>
        </reportElement>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="70" y="0" width="300" height="100" uuid="0a866eb3-85cf-4376-d6a4-21b534d36df0"/>
            <text><![CDATA[MIDDLE PAGE HEADER TEXT 1]]></text>
        </staticText>
    </frame>
</band>
</pageHeader>
```

I'm using `frame` blocks along with `printWhenExpression`. Depending on the `printWhenExpression` condition, only one of two `frame` blocks should be printed (with all of its content). First frame block should render "last page header", and second one should render "middle pages header".

The problem lies within the first `frame` ("last page header") `printWhenExpression`:

```
<printWhenExpression>
    <![CDATA[new Boolean($V{PAGE_NUMBER} == $V{PAGE_COUNT})]]>
</printWhenExpression>
```

In this case, `$V{PAGE_NUMBER}` always equals `$V{PAGE_COUNT}` because of the evaluation time.

Is there any way to check if the current page is the last page? Also, is there any other way to enable "middle pages" and "last page" headers?

**NOTE:** I was able to implement similar logic for the footers by using the `frames` and `Last Page Footer` band!

Comment: Hi @PetterFriberg. I'm trying to implement your solution, but `currentPage` variable returns `null` on all pages except the first one.

Comment: I'm using "Jaspersoft iReport Designer 5.6.0" with "JDK 1.7.0_79".

Comment: If you copy the variable expression in your jrxml and the textField in your pageHeader (setting position if its out of band), you should see the different text's on the different page groups... I have tried it in iReport Designer 5.6.0 and exporting to pdf with jasper report 6.

Comment: I have done everything you suggested but still without luck. Here is [the jasper template](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nrtlw403xj5fqgg/Example2.jrxml?dl=0) that I'm using along with [the xml datasource](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ixz4qc68snoq6g7/Example.xml?dl=0).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97451/discussion-between-petter-friberg-and-mrm).

Comment: I have update my answer with the solution that I think is the best one for this question (using negative coordinates), removed currentPage solution since it does not work with jr:list and jr:table as updated question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all: `$V{PAGE_COUNT}` is

> the **number of records** that were processed when generating the **current page**. Hence the number of records you have in the page, not a page number count...

In `pageFooter` and `lastPageFooter` the `reportElement` can have **negative Y** coordinates (if IDE does not allow this then you need to edit manually the jrxml) es. y="-700", which allows you to put information in pageHeader and last pageHeader...

**FIRST PAGE**

in frame use:

```
<printWhenExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean($V{PAGE_NUMBER}.intValue()==1)]]></printWhenExpression>
```

- **pageHeader** use `title` band or put frame in `pageFooter` and use negative y coordinate.
- **pageFooter**, use `pageFooter` band

**MIDDLE PAGE**

on frame use:

```
<printWhenExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean($V{PAGE_NUMBER}.intValue()>1)]]></printWhenExpression>
```

- **pageHeader** put frame in `pageFooter` and use negative y coordinate.
- **pageFooter**, use `pageFooter` band.

**LAST PAGE**

- **pageHeader**, put frame in `lastPageFooter` and use negative y coordinate.
- **pageFooter**, use `lastPageFooter` band

**NOTE:** To generate space for this virtual pageHeader include an empty `pageHeader` with desired band height

Have Fun!

Comment: Since I need to support lists or tables in the reports, it seams that the workaround with negative Y coordinates on Last page footer is the only solution. Thank you @Petter, as always very precise answer.

Comment: You shouldn't have removed your workaround with custom `currentPage` variable, it can be useful for someone.

Comment: @mrm  I think this is cleaner from jasper report point of view... (even if its not nice in IDE).. the currentPage was 1/2 hack and as so it did not work with components... (if someone likes to find it they can check revision history.... ; )