# Jasperreports: How to put a summary chart only in the report first page?

Tags: jasper-reports

I wanted to use the concept of bands to put the "Summary" band right after title but this is not possible.

If I put the chart in the "Page Header" band chart is repeated across all the report pages. I only want to have the chart in the first page and let the table details in the next pages without having a repeated chart in every page.

Comment: Have you tried putting the chart into the title band?

Comment: Shall I make that an actual answer or do you want to make that yourself?

Comment: Yes, please. Thank you, Mkl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to put content only onto the first page is by adding it to the `title` band.

If this is not possible, e.g. because your desired content shall be displayed after some material in the page header band, look for other options [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34185100/1729265) which use frames with print-when-expressions like this

```xml
<printWhenExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean($V{PAGE_NUMBER}.intValue()==1)]]></printWhenExpression>
```

in other bands.